# Includes method doesnt return true for key extracted from Object.entries of Array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter objects who key's correspond to values in an array of arrays. So 3 sets of objects each filtered by their placement in an array. (Objects are listed in an array.) I suspect this is a two-part question. Why doesn't the Array.prototype.includes method return true, when the case is true?

```
boardObj =  [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

const winCol = (boardObj) => {
        const indexes = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8]];
        let result = indexes.filter((ele) => {
            for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(boardObj)) {
                console.log(ele.includes(0))
                console.log(ele.includes(k))
                if (ele.includes(k)) {
                     return v
                }
            }
            
        })
        console.log(result)
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the expected input and the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property names are always **string values**:

```js
console.log(typeof Object.keys({0: 42})[0]);
```

But `Array#includes` basically performs strict comparison, so string values will never be equal to number values.

You can convert your `indexes` array to an array of arrays of string values, or convert the property name to a number value.

```js
console.log(
  [0,1,2].includes(Number(Object.keys({0: 42})[0]))
);
console.log(
  ['0','1','2'].includes(Object.keys({0: 42})[0])
);
```

You could also use `Array#some` and perform "loose" comparison instead:

```js
const key = Object.keys({0: 42})[0];
console.log([0,1,2].some(e => e == key));
```

Comment: Sweet this worked for me! if (ele.includes(Number(k))) {
                     return v
                }